# How to return other value during autocompletion using typeahead?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, typeahead

This is my implementation of autocomplete using `rails` and `typeahead`

```
  def autocomplete
    render json: Product.ac_search(params[:query].to_s)
  end

$ ->
  $('#order_id').typeahead
    name: "name"
    valueKey: "name"
    remote: "/products/autocomplete?query=%QUERY"

= simple_form_for @order do |form|
  = form.input :product_id, as: :string
```

Example of products hash:

```
[{"id":"8004","name":"cow leg"}, {"id":"8004","name":"dog leg"}]
```

How to select item by name by return an id if product?

Comment: what typeahead plugin are you using?....should have a `select` event callback that provides access to item selected

Comment: I am using http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...using custom event outlined in plugin docs:

```
$('#order_id').on('typeahead:selected',function(evt,data){
   alert(data.id);
})
```

Comment: and how to set this data.id as field value?

Comment: `$(selector).val(data.id)`